# NotificationCompat.Builder, как использовать channelId?

Tags: android

В Android.O старый билдер

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context)
```

объявлен устаревшим.

Теперь надо указывать второй параметр

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)
```

В принципе довольно много в интернетах про то, что это такое и с чем его едят, но, во всех примерах, этот самый `NotificationChannel` создается ровно перед вызовом `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Собственно вопрос. Это действительно нормально, перед созданием каждого нового уведомления создавать ему канал, или всё же оно работает как-то по другому? Здравый смысл подсказывает, что создавать канал логично всего один раз и использовать все время жизни приложения, нет?

Может дадите ссылок на грамотную статью по этому вопросу?

**PS [Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). ЧИТАТЬ СТРОГО НА АНГЛИЙСКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ! Русская версия страницы сильно устарела.**

Comment: [Attempting to create an existing notification channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to perform the preceding sequence of steps when starting an app.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: @YuraIvanov в русской версии старая дока, без описания каналов, а кнопку смены языка еще поискать надо. Не ожидал от гугла...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня так реализовано, создаю один раз

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      NotificationChannel notificationChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
      if (notificationChannel == null) {
          int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
          notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Имя канала", importance);
          notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
          notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
          notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
      }
  }
```