# Не работает NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: java, android, android-notification

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = NotificationManagerCompat.getNotificationChannel("MyID");
        if (notificationChannel == null) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("MyID", "Имя канала", importance);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
            NotificationManagerCompat.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .build();
```

Делал все как и в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778427/notificationcompat-builder-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-channelid), но ничего не работает, а "createNotificationChannel" подсвечивает как ошибку.

Comment: Метод `createNotificationChannel` подсвечивается как ошибка, потому что нет такого статического метода в классе [`NotificationManagerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать просто `NotificationManager`:

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

или на джаве:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

также хочу уточнить что вы пытаетесь использовать не экземпляр класса `NotificationManagerCompat`. То есть вам нужно предварительно создать его перед использованием, а вы даже не вызываете конструктор:

```
private NotificationManagerCompat(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
```

поэтому и не вызывается ничего. Сделайте так:

```
NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(someContext);
```

и дальше уже вызывайте метод:

```
   public void createNotificationChannel(@NonNull NotificationChannel channel) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

[Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat) по `NotificationManagerCompat`.

Comment: NotificationManagerCompat.from(context). и проверка на версию sdk не нужна, в этом смысл compat'а, он сам проверяет.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо за замечание, по поводу проверки версии - метод я скопировал из доков compat'a)) там оно как вы правильно заметили и проверяет